# navigation pane in Bootstrap4 not showing correct content

Tags: bootstrap-4

In the following code, I see only `Lorem Ipsum events` irrespective of the tab I have selected. What is the mistake?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs flex-column flex-sm-row" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="events-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#services-events" role="tab" aria-controls="events" aria-selected="true"> Events</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="personal-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#services-personal" role="tab" aria-controls="personal" aria-selected="false"> Personal</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="prints-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#services-prints" role="tab" aria-controls="prints" aria-selected="false"> Prints</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="events" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="events-tab">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <p> Lorem Ipsum events </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="personal" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="personal-tab">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <p> Lorem Ipsum personal </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="prints"  role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="prints-tab">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <p> Lorem Ipsum prints</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the `href`s to refer to the `id`s of the tab panes.

Example: href `#personal` will toggle the personal tab (with the id `personal`).